# Can I sync my iPhone with the new Apple Photos app via iTunes / without iCloud?

Tags: data-synchronization, photos, photos.app

I would like to sync my photos from my Mac to my iPhone using the new Apple Photos app without using iCloud, like it was possible with the old iPhoto app and iTunes on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible with iTunes 12.1.2 which was released today.

Comment: I didn't need iTunes 12.1.2 and could just plug in the phone and use Photos to import photos directly. Updating probably won't hurt.

Comment: But not sync the other direcion